# Pycharm: terminate all running processes

Tags: python, pycharm

PyDev has a feature to terminate all running processes. Does PyCharm have something similar? I only see a "stop" button in the menu.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

PyCharm has an option to stop all processes now in the **Navigation Bar**.

I'm using 2021.2.3 version.

[image: PyCharm 's stop all running processes button]

Answer (score 28):

I found this solution:

it is running as a java process, so the best way is to kill it by using:

```
killall java -9
```

(Caveat: Only run if you don't have any other java processes, otherwise use `top` or the Ubuntu system monitor and find which process number it is.)

Answer (score 2):

`Ctrl-Shift-F4` closes just one tab. 
`Right-click` on the `run`-bar next to `Run:` > `Close All`

Comment: "Close all" does work, but it asks you about every process whether you want to terminate it...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force all running processes to stop at once just kill python process. On Windows this can easily be done by clicking 'End Process' on the Task Manager (on the Processes tab).

This is quite usefull if you end up stuck with some running ghost processes of your python app in the background as I had (even when PyCharm was closed).

Comment: I do use that when I can. "killall python" works on linux just fine. Usually, however, I have some other python processes running in the background that I don't want to kill, so this solution is not applicable.

Comment: In that case it's not applicable you're right. I'm sorry I don't have another solution.

Answer (score 1):

In PyCharm, if you click on the bottom right ... "Running x processes", then x number of windows pop up. (Here, x is the number of processing running.)

Each has an X button to kill the process.

Comment: For Pycharm, `esc`, to close things at the bottom and `enter`, to confirm is unfortunately not obvious. Long live Autohotkey.

Answer (score 0):

To kill a Python program, when the program is called from within a **Terminal** opened in **PyCharm**, either:

- right-click in the terminal window and select "**Close Session**" from the dropdown menu
- press `Ctrl + Shift - W`